# How to show the value of a variable in GUI using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to display the value of the variable `var` in GUI using tkinter with the `set` method.
It shows the text without the value when I run the program. What should I modify to make it display the value of the variable `var`?

My code:

```
# import modules
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox

def cricket_info():

    try:
       # match = sports.get_match(sports.CRICKET, e1.get() , e2.get())
        var=45
        date.set(str(var))

    except:
        messagebox.showerror("showerror", "No match found")




# object of tkinter
# and background set for light grey
master = Tk()
master.configure(bg='light grey')

# Variable Classes in tkinter
date = StringVar();


# Creating label for each information
# name using widget Label
Label(master, text="Date :" , bg = "light grey").grid(row=2, sticky=W)



# Creating lebel for class variable
# name using widget Entry
Label(master, text="", textvariable= date ,bg = "light grey").grid(row=2,column=1, sticky=W)



e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

e2 = Entry(master)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

# creating a button using the widget
# Button that will call the submit function
b = Button(master, text="Show", command=cricket_info )
b.grid(row=0, column=2,columnspan=2, rowspan=2,padx=5, pady=5)

mainloop()
```

Comment: suggestion: You should use `master.mainloop()`, related: try: `StringVar(master=master)`

Comment: Hi, I implement your suggestion. The problem is not solved

Comment: You're getting an unexpected exception in the `cricket_info()` function because there is no variable named `sports` defined.

Comment: First of it works (shows `45`) if not using the `match = sport...` line (I commented it out because otherwise it just throws an error which is catched by `except`) , second if nothing shows up nor does the error msgbox show up it could be an issue with something else for example python version (what version are You using?)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that has the variable `sports` defined.

Comment: Most likely there is another instance of `Tk()` elsewhere.

Comment: I coomented out the match. there is no instance of tk() elsewhere

Comment: I want to print the value of random variable in a gui interface. If someone has suggestions let me know..

Comment: It's not meaningful to specify both `text=` and `textvariable=` for a Label.  In a quick test, I found that `textvariable=` took precedence, but I couldn't find that documented anywhere, so perhaps it might not be true for every Tkinter version.  Try getting rid of the `text=""` option, that's the only thing that looks suspicious about your code.  (If that's not it, I agree with @acw1668 that the problem looks exactly like multiple calls to Tk() during a single run of Python.)